# Correct decryption returns empty string

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I am trying to decrypt some data that I have stored in my db.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

I have checked and rechecked all the values that I am passing in and seem to be identical to the ones I used for encrypting.

Also whenever i pass in an incorrect key it does produce output but whenever i'm passing the right key it returns an empty string.

And the funny thing is that javascript doesn't see it as an empty string although firebug shows it as one.

My code for encryption:

```
$iv = hash('sha256',$_POST['ben'].$_POST['assetName'],true);
$secretKeyFromAnswer = hash('sha256',$_POST['answer'],true);
$encedUsername = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secretKeyFromAnswer , $_POST['username'], MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
```

My code for decryption:

```
$hashKey = hash('sha256',$_POST['key'],true);
$iv = hash('sha256',$_POST['ben'].$_POST['assetName'],true);
$theData = base64_decode($userToDec);
$decUsername = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $hashKey, $theData , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv),'\0');
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not running the encryption on an empty string?

Comment: You are the man! Had a typo in my jquery code and was in fact reading an empty string before encrypting! Put up an answer if you want so i can accept and u get your rep! Cheers

Comment: I turned the comment @AtkinsSJ left into a Community Wiki answer so that this question isn't lingering forever as "unanswered" and/or "no accepted answer".

Answer (score 2):

"Are you sure you're not running the encryption on an empty string?" -- [AtkinsSJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178345/atkinssj)

> You are the man! Had a typo in my jquery code and was in fact reading an empty string before encrypting! Put up an answer if you want so i can accept and u get your rep! Cheers